How to compile paragraphs in separate word documents into one collecion document
Every month, we discuss specific topics and create a report in Word.
It would be helpful to group the specific topics into separate documents so that we have everything discussed about each topic in one place.
Master and subdocuments work the other way around: they split a large document into smaller ones.
What I’d like to do is mark the sections related to Topic 1 (and Topic 2, etc.) and compile them into a collection document.
Is that even possible? Does anyone have any ideas on how to achieve this?
Thanks for thinking along.
Kem

This isn't even necessarily a programming question. If you bookmark the ranges in each document (e.g. giving each topic a set bookmark name), you could reference those bookmarked ranges in another document via INCLUDETEXT fields.

Wow. That's a simple and great solution. I haven't even thought about that. I'm going to give it a try. Thank you.
